# Golang append map в for rows.Next()

Tags: golang

Использую

```
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/lib/pq"
```

Созданный map внутри цикла имеет рандомное расположение элементов, то есть расположены не в порядке добавления.

```
for rows.Next(){
//....
err = rows.Scan(&xx,&cc,&vv,&bb)
//....
zz := make(map[string][]string)
zz[xx] = append(zz[xx],cc,vv,bb)
}
fmt.Println(zz) // И всегда рандомное расположение.
```

Как победить и понять?

Comment: На то он и map, что бы порядок был "произвольным". Хотите строгий порядок - используйте массив.

Comment: Вам надо комментарий как ответ оформлять

Comment: @KoVadim чушь же, если создать вне цикла ( в ручную ) порядок будет соблюден.

Comment: Никакой чуши, ковадим правильно говорит. Это документированное поведение: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types "A map is an unordered group of elements...". В 1.3 выдача была неслучайной и это был баг, который специально фиксили - как раз чтобы никто на порядок элементов не закладывался: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8410

Comment: У автора вопроса еще одна особенность - данные приходят с базы. А если делать select запрос без явного указания сортировки, то база имеет право отдавать записи в произвольном порядке (да, многие так не делают, но имеют законное право).

Comment: Созданный ручками map какой магией имеет порядок ?

Comment: @KoVadim с базы селект с сортировкой, бд отдает в отсортированном виде.

Comment: и да, версия 1.5.2

Comment: В целом все ясно, спасибо за помощь, очевидное как всегда лежало на поверхности.

Comment: @KoVadim Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `map` в Go порядок обхода заведомо случайный. И это не побочный эффект, авторы специально его рандомизируют, см. [go1.19/src/runtime/map.go:844](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.19/src/runtime/map.go#L844):

```
// decide where to start
var r uintptr
if h.B > 31-bucketCntBits {
    r = uintptr(fastrand64())
} else {
    r = uintptr(fastrand())
}
```

Но это особенность реализации, в [документации](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Map_types) говорится лишь о том, что:

> A map is an *unordered* group of elements

То есть, нам просто никто не обещает упорядоченность. Рандомизация же помогает не привязываться к конкретному порядку.

Возможно, автора вопроса ввел в заблуждение тот факт, что при выводе `map` через функцию `fmt.Println()` (и др. из этого пакета), порядок будет фиксированный. Но это [особенность реализации самой функции](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.19/src/fmt/print.go#L800).

Если нужен фиксированный порядок побхода, то лучше использовать Slice / Array вместо Map. Либо использовать вспомогательный Slice:

```
m := map[string]int{"Ivan": 44, "Petr": 22, "Anna": 26}

keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))

// сортируем ключи
for k := range m {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
sort.Strings(keys)

// с помощью отсортированных ключей выводим значения map
for _, k := range keys {
    fmt.Println(k, m[k])
}
```

Если интересно, почему оно устроено именно так, у меня есть хороший [ролик о внутреннем устройстве типа Map в Go](https://youtu.be/P_SXTUiA-9Y).